# mounting a RAID in /etc/fstab

Tags: raid, mount, fstab

Hi I have a raid mounting in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/md/debian\:0          /home           ext4    defaults        0        0
```

but if I do `mount -a`
It gives me error `mount: /home: special device /dev/md/debian\:0 doest not exists`

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I removed the backslash before `:` => `/dev/md/debian:0` and now It works, I don't know why but before It worked with the backslash

Comment: I'd probably replace that device name with the file system UUID.